# Custom listview hava error with IllegalStateException in android

Tags: android, listview

Who knows the error！

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131558443, class com.torrap.trunk.ui.views.exlist.ActionSlideExpandableListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1545)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4559)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ooh, I think the error is:  The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you call `notifyuDataSetChanged` on your adapter as soon as the data changes.